# Can't access WordPress dashboard unless Administrator

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, roles, dashboard

Our non-Administrator (Shop Manager, Editor, Author, etc) users cannot access the WordPress/Woocommerce dashboard. Administrators can access the dashboard.

- I have tried logging in users as "out of the box" Shop Managers, Authors, Editors, and they get bumped back to the storefront.
- I have tried disabling plugins, and using the basic woo theme to no avail.
- I have tried accessing admin pages they should have access to directly, but still cannot access.

Can anyone share any suggestions for getting our non-Administrators access to the dashboard?

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Try reverting your theme back to the standard TwentyFifteen to eliminate any theme functions causing this?  If it works, you have something probably in the theme's functions.php file that's redirecting users.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. We tried using TwentyFifteen and the same problem occured.

Comment: Can those same users log in if you change their access levels to administrator?  Also try switching to twenty fifteen with woocommerce disabled then you can see if it's a woocommerce issue or a core wordpress one

Comment: I tried disabling everything including Woocommerce, and switched the theme to TwentyFifteen. Turned off all caching. The non-admins still get bumped to the blog home page.

If I switch the same user to Administrator role, they can log in.

Comment: Strange.  I'm not sure what else to suggest except maybe to check your .htaccess file?  Can you post that?

Answer (score 1):

- Try to disable ALL the plugins at the same time.
- If it works then enable the plugins one by one to find the culprit.
- If its still doesnt work make sure you have the latest version or
  Wordpress/WooCommerce.
- If everything is up to date and its still doesnt work then look into the functions.php file in
  your theme, maybe there is some script that causes the problem..

If nothing of these has worked you could always apply a patch until you find the real source of the problem, here is some suggestions:

- Do a temporary quick fix by using the [user_has_cap filter](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/user_has_cap)
- Add capabilties to user roles so the will be able to access like an administratior see the  [add_cap()](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_cap) function

Comment: Tried disabling all the plugins by renaming the plugin folder to _plugins. When all the plugins are disabled, the non-Administrators can log in. Now need to identify the plugin causing the problem. Just curious - can a host install hidden plugins?

Comment: You can have plugins in the mu-plugins folder (Must Use plugins). But they are not hidden.
But IMO its just one plugin or a combination of plugins thats causes you trouble!

Answer (score 1):

If you have installed Ultimate Member plugin:

- Go to User Roles page
- Press Edit on the role that you want to access the dashboard
- Check: Can access wp-admin?
- Press Update role
- Then test; it should work then